# Rails: Touch user column when saving separate db model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

What I'd like to do is fairly simple.  It would look something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: tags
#
#  id                          :integer          not null, primary key
#  tagname                     :string(255)
#  user_id                     :integer
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # WHEN TAG GETS SAVED, UPDATE CORRECT USER COLUMN
  on_save_do ->{ User.find(user_id).current_tag = User.find(user_id).current_tag || id }

end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  current_tag            :integer
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
end
```

So all I need is to make sure the first time a tag is saved for a user that it saves the current tag id to the users current_tag column with the tag_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  after_save :update_user_tag

  private

  def update_user_tag
    user.current_tag = id
    user.save if user.changed?
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe you've got it.  But I'm not setting the string tagname, but the tag_id as a reference from User.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up using.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  after_save proc { user = User.find(self.user_id); user.current_tag = user.current_tag || self.id; user.save }
end
```